# Angularjs Request Body to be used in Rails 4

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-resource

In Rails 4, the default body to be sended to the server is different to the usual, the object need to be a child object.

Normally, taking some `user` object as example, we send a body like this:

```
{
   "name" : "Foo",
   "age" : "99"
}
```

But in Rails 4 i need to do this:

```
{ 
   "user" : {
       "name" : "Foo",
       "age" : "99"
   }
}
```

**Problem**: How to insert the class name as root of the request body automatically (using the variable name ou factory name) making the body as child like above?

I'm using the `$resource` to make API calls, I try to modify the data value in `transformRequest` function but I will lose the information about the `$resolved` field and I don't know if this can be a problem later.

Did someone have a simple solution for this problem? Will be good to still using `$resource` to make the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Interceptors

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests. The interceptors leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this
>   need for both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.

Comment: Right, but httpInterceptor or some interceptor for each factory that have the $resource methods? I tried to use the httpInterceptor but i didn't find a way to know the class name to put as root of the json body. Thanks in advance